# How do you find the eccentricity of an ellipse given the intersection points with a circle that shares the center with the ellipse?

Tags: circles

I was wondering how to find the equation of an ellipse with points that intersect a circle with the same center. I attempted to solve it using these following parameters:
(a,b) , (c,d) , (e,f) , (g,h) are the intersection points
r is the radius of a circle. 
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: The title and the question don't match.

Comment: As Yves Daoust’s answer shows, this isn’t enough information to identify the ellipse. The problem is that you don’t have enough _independent_ constraints: two sets of three points are colinear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. In the figure, the two ellipses have the same common points.

[image]